# find_committee() missing 1 required positional argument: 'profile'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using a special package named python multiwinner package.

I'm trying to use a method named experiment.run in order to run my results few times.

the code is:

```
from pmp.experiments import ExperimentConfig, generate_uniform, Experiment, generate_gauss
from pmp.rules import Bloc, Borda, SNTV
from pmp.preferences import Approval, Ordinal
from pmp.preferences import Profile
from pmp.experiments import experiment_config
from pmp.experiments import generate_uniform, impartial

# Generating voters and candidates using functions and lambdas
config = experiment_config.ExperimentConfig()
config.set_candidates(generate_uniform(-3, -3, 3, 3, 100, 'None'))
config.add_candidates(lambda: generate_uniform(-3, -3, 3, 3, 10, 'None'))
config.add_voters(generate_uniform(-3, -3, 3, 3, 10, 'None'))
config.add_command(impartial(5,6))
config.get_commands()
preferences = [Ordinal(o) for o in config.get_voters()]
profile = Profile(config.get_candidates(), preferences)


experiment = Experiment(config)
experiment.set_election(Bloc, 3)
experiment.set_result_filename("bloc3")
experiment.set_generated_dir_path("bloc_example")

experiment.run(visualization=True, n=2, save_win=True)
```

I get exception `TypeError: find_committee() missing 1 required positional argument: 'profile'`

When I go to the traceback I see those methods:

```
    def __run_election(self, candidates, preferences):
        """
        :param candidates:
        :type candidates: List
        :param preferences:
        :type preferences: List[Preference]

        Run election, compute winners
        """
        seed()

        profile = Profile(candidates, preferences)
        if self.k > len(candidates):
            print("k is too big. Not enough candidates to find k winners.")
            return

        return self.rule.find_committee(self.k, profile)
```

and the code is failing on this line:

```
 winners = self.__run_election(candidates, preferences)
                if log_on:
                    print('Winners', winners)
```

Is it something in the package itself I can easily add? because I do see the "profile" inside __run_election, so I don't understand why It can't pass it.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the content of profile after execution of ```profile = Profile(candidates, preferences)```?

Comment: It's storing the voters and they preferences, for example there's 3 candidates and one voter rank them by his preference. An output example of the profile: Profile with 3 voters and 3 candidates: <pmp.preferences.ordinal.Ordinal object at 0x000001B9B136FE80>, <pmp.preferences.ordinal.Ordinal object at 0x000001B9B0D47670>, <pmp.preferences.ordinal.Ordinal object at 0x000001B9B14A4F70>